# Build Android standalone toolchain on OS X fails - "darwin-x86_64 is not supported by the source NDK"

Tags: macos, android-ndk

I'm trying to build Firefox for Android on my Mac running OS X El Capitan following the instructions at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_for_Android_build.  My first attempt failed because Android for Firefox seems unable to build using the `r11b` NDK installed by the `bootstrap.py` script, so I downloaded and installed the `r10e` NDK mentioned variously on the Mozilla page.  I've gotten as far as the `./mach build` step which fails with

```
 0:06.01 checking for the Android toolchain directory...
 0:06.01 DEBUG: Trying /Users/fkoschara/.mozbuild/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
 0:06.01 DEBUG: Trying /Users/fkoschara/.mozbuild/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86
 0:06.01 DEBUG: Trying /Users/fkoschara/.mozbuild/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
 0:06.01 DEBUG: Trying /Users/fkoschara/.mozbuild/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86
 0:06.01 DEBUG: Trying /Users/fkoschara/.mozbuild/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
 0:06.01 DEBUG: Trying /Users/fkoschara/.mozbuild/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/darwin-x86
 0:06.01 ERROR: You have to specify --with-android-toolchain=/path/to/ndk/toolchain.
```

because

```
ls: /Users/fkoschara/.mozbuild/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64: No such file or directory
```

I tried creating a standalone toolchain, but when I ran `$ ~/.mozbuild/android-ndk/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --platform=android-21 --system=darwin-x86_64 --install-dir=/Users/fkoschara/.mozbuild/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64` I got

```
Host system 'darwin-x86_64' is not supported by the source NDK!
Try --system=<name> with one of:  linux-x86_64
```

I tried again without the `--system=darwin-x86_64` and got

```
Host system 'darwin-x86' is not supported by the source NDK!
Try --system=<name> with one of:  linux-x86_64
```

What do I have to do to get a Darwin toolchain so I can do this cross compilation?

Comment: Looks like you installed NDK r10e for Linux o your Mac

Comment: @AlexCohn - You're right.  Now that you point it out, the answer is obvious - I installed the NDK I'm using on the CentOS VM on the Mac.  I wish your comment was an answer so I could accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Android Studio bundles, NDK distribution used to be plain ZIP files, so it was easy to make a mistake that happened for you: install NDK on a wrong platform. In your case, you happened to install a Linux 64-bit version on Mac. There is no surprise that this will not work. I was surprised you could even run `ndk-build`, because usually it uses a bundled version of `make`, not the one installed in the system. Maybe the part of choosing the correct `make` was omitted from the story of your tribulations.